# Nice way to create a dynamic 2D matrix in C++ 11

Tags: c++, c++11

I already know how to create a dynamic 2D matrix using `new` and free it using `delete`. Since C++ 11 is here with many new memory features such as `unique_ptr`, `array` container etc.; what is a nice way to create a 2D matrix so that one needs not to free the matrix explicitly using `delete` operator?

Comment: Can you clarify whether the matrix dimensions are konwn at compile-time?

Comment: Yes they are known at compile time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the simplest ways is to use a vector of vectors

```
const int N = 10;
const int M = 10;
vector<vector<int>> matrix2d(N, vector<int>(M, 0)); // 10x10 zero-initialized matrix
matrix2d[0][0] = 42;
```

You could of course use a single vector and wrap it into an accessor class

```
vector<int> matrix(N * M, 0) // Ditto as above, but needs stride-aware accessors
```

I'll post a small example here for completeness' sake

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix2D {
    std::vector<T> data;
    unsigned int sizeX, sizeY;
public:
    Matrix2D (unsigned int x, unsigned int y)
        : sizeX (x), sizeY (y) {
        data.resize (sizeX*sizeY);
    }

    T& operator()(unsigned int x, unsigned int y) {
        if (x >= sizeX || y>= sizeY)
            throw std::out_of_range("OOB access"); // Throw something more appropriate
        return data[sizeX*y + x]; // Stride-aware access
    }
};
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba976ff174cb7c51)</kbd>

or perhaps combine your way with a [smart pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). Notice that the `vector<vector<int>>` approach should be used with caution since the vectors are independent from each other and there's nothing to enforce that they should keep their size fixed.

Comment: It would be better use a single vector `vector<int> matrix_data(N * M, 0)` wrapped by a class with 2d accessors

Comment: I'll propose that as another solution. This has the advantage of being easy to understand and use although it's definitely suboptimal.

Comment: Since I saw many approaches above, it just came to my mind that if the following approach is memory leak safe.

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
 
using namespace std; 

int main()
{
 size_t N = 10, M = 4;
    
 vector< vector<int> > my_arr(N);

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < N; i++)
     my_arr[i] = vector<int>(M);
     
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
     for(unsigned j = 0; j < M; j++)
      cout << my_arr[i][j] << " ";
     cout << endl;
 }
 
 return 0;
}

Comment: @AnirbanGhosh using `std::vector` is memory-leak safe since the container manages the allocation and deallocation for you.

Comment: Throw `std::out_of_range`, which inherits from `logic_error` iirc.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly suggest using [`array_view`](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/array_view.h) from the [GSL](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL), which will eventually be part of the standard.

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include "array_view.h" // must be manually imported until standardization

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 10>  arr{}; // 10 ints on the stack
    std::vector<int>  vec{12}; // 12 ints on the heap
    auto a = gsl::array_view<int, 2>{{2, 5}, arr}; // 2D, 2x5 matrix
    auto b = gsl::array_view<int, 3>{{3, 2, 2}, vec}; // 3D, 3x2x2 matrix
    auto c = gsl::array_view<int>{vec}; // 1D, spans from `begin()` to `end()`
    a[{0,3}] += b[{0,1,1}] * -c[2]; // access syntax
}
```

N.B. `array_view` holds *no control* over the lifetime of the range it looks at.  See [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3851.pdf) for full details.

### Edit:

array_view is dead as it was becoming too complicated in handling multidimensional arrays with zero cost abstraction. You should instead use [span](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/gsl/span) from the [GSL](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL).

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45723820/4126976) for more information about span.

Comment: N.b. this question is tagged with C++11. Not sure if OP can make use of this.

Comment: @Marco GSL supports C++11 as it's a header-only library, it's just one include away.  I feel it's important to have a forward-looking solution for the question as well, since this will be in the standard eventually.

Comment: Makes sense. I would prefer it as well

Comment: `array` must have size known at compile-time. OP was unclear but I think he means that the size may not be known until runtime

Comment: @M.M Well, as long as the rank doesn't change (if it did, it would require a different type for most approaches anyway) one could emulate dynamic sizes by changing the bounds of the `array_view`.  Also, `array_view` works with _any_ contiguous sequence, _including vectors_ (so runtime changes are possible).

Comment: @M.M The OP was later clarified in the comments. The size is known at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

Based on above answers, I have found a simple way to create matrices although not using C++11 features. Here is an illustration.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std; 

typedef vector<vector<int>> Matrix2D;
typedef vector<Matrix2D> Matrix3D;

Matrix2D my_arr;

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 9;

    for(unsigned s = 4; s <= N; s++)
    {       
        my_arr.resize(s);
        for(unsigned i = 0; i < s; i++)
            my_arr[i].resize(s,s);

        for(unsigned i = 0; i < s; i++)
        {
            for(unsigned j = 0; j < s; j++)
                cout << my_arr[i][j] << " ";
            cout << endl;
        }

        cout << "\n\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Considering you want to use an array known at compile time, using a `std::vector` is a bad idea.  You should use at least use a `std::array` instead.  I still, however, strongly suggest using my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I am wondering if the array container can be resized when required like vectors.

Comment: No they can't, but in that case you never wanted a compile-time array in the first place.  Compile-time means it will never change, which is why `std::array` would be preferred.  Otherwise `std::vector` would be the way to go.  However, you should still place it _flatly_, because otherwise you'll suffer from locality issues. (vector of vector of vector of ints (3D matrix) means **3** pointer dereferences when only 1 is necessary.  This _will_ bite you back as you make and iterate over bigger matrices)

Comment: I see your point. Thank you very much. I will try to follow your approach then.

Comment: Since this is basically my answer it would be nice to be awarded some points.