# Using vector as matrix?

Tags: c++, stl

How may I define a vector in C++11 such that its size is 4*5 so I can treat it like a matrix?
(I mean using operator `[]` like the following)

```
mat[2][3];
```

---

Update:
The following gives me error:

```
#include <memory>
class Test{
        std::vector<int> vect;
};
```

Error message:

```
implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >'
    std::vector<int> vect;
```

Comment: nobody is downvoting every question of yours. If this would happen there are mechanisms in place to revert serial voting

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32915825/nice-way-to-create-a-dynamic-2d-matrix-in-c-11

Comment: @idclev463035818 this happened to my last 7 questions, once I publish it within 2 seconds I get downvoting

Comment: fwiw, from your last 3 question none includes a mcve or any attempt from your side and the fourth and older question all have 0 downvotes...

Comment: You need to `#include<vector>`.

Answer (score 3):

You just need a nested `vector`, like this:

```
auto v = std::vector<std::vector<int>>(4, std::vector<int>(5));
```

and you can then index it like `v[0][0]`.

Comment: can't I create it as one single vector (for efficency)

Comment: Yes, of course. Did you see the link that was posted in the comments? See the dupe target.

Comment: But I'm getting an error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >'
        std::vector<int> vect; when I type std::vector<int> vect;

Comment: Ok, then update the question with what you've tried, and show a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Done that, take a look if possible

Answer (score 0):

The error `implicit instantiation of undefined template std::__1::vector ...` means `std::vector` is unknown to the compiler.

You need to `#include <vector>`